# Android 2.0 contact groups manipulation

Tags: android, contacts

I would manipulate the contact groups in Android 2.O. My code is following:

To get a list of group (with id and title):

```
final String[] GROUP_PROJECTION = new String[] { ContactsContract.Groups._ID, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE };
Cursor cursor = ctx.managedQuery(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI, GROUP_PROJECTION, null, null, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE + " ASC");
```

Later, on an ListView, I select a group (onClick event) and read all contacts belong to this selected group by following code:

```
    String where = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID
            + "="
            + groupid
            + " AND "
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE
            + "='"
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
            + "'";
```

Problem: ContactsContract.Groups._ID in the first query does not match with the ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID in the second query.

Any solution/suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked a lot with Contact Groups, and as I remember those code fragments up there are from my other posts. The code does work for me, and should work for you too.

I don't see why the two data should not match. Please double check again.

Comment: Hi Pentium10, I know this question has been long overdue. But I have a short question to ask regarding this Group/Groupmembership. Have you encountered a missing groupmembership row_id before? I noticed that source_id and row_id return the same result.