# How can i get a groupId / GroupName of a Contact in Android?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I am having list of contacts present in an Android device. I want to fetch the associated groupIds and GroupName of all the contacts. I have been trying to use ContactsContract.Groups._ID to get the ID, but I am not able to get it. Can someone provide me other way to get the groupID of contact?

Comment: Have you looked at this? It may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026750/android-2-0-contact-groups-manipulation

Comment: giZm0 is on the right track with the `GroupMembership` view... keep in mind though that a contact can belong to more than one group.

Answer (score 7):

This is how I do it. You can probably mess around and find a faster solution by not doing two queries.

The idea is to get the row id of the group from the Data table using `GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID`. When you have the row id you use that to query the Groups table to get the name (Title) of the group.

Often the `Groups.TITLE` isn't that good a name and you probably will have to format it or search around to find anything better.

**Here is the code to get contact id:**

```
public long getGroupIdFor(Long contactId){
    Uri uri = Data.CONTENT_URI;
    String where = String.format(
            "%s = ? AND %s = ?",
            Data.MIMETYPE,
            GroupMembership.CONTACT_ID);

    String[] whereParams = new String[] {
               GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
               Long.toString(contactId),
    };

    String[] selectColumns = new String[]{
            GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID,
    };


    Cursor groupIdCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
            uri, 
            selectColumns, 
            where, 
            whereParams, 
            null);
    try{
        if (groupIdCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return groupIdCursor.getLong(0);
        }
        return Long.MIN_VALUE; // Has no group ...
    }finally{
        groupIdCursor.close();
    }
}
```

**And here is the code to get the Title of the group:**

```
public String getGroupNameFor(long groupId){
    Uri uri = Groups.CONTENT_URI;
    String where = String.format("%s = ?", Groups._ID);
    String[] whereParams = new String[]{Long.toString(groupId)};
    String[] selectColumns = {Groups.TITLE};
    Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
            uri, 
            selectColumns,
            where, 
            whereParams, 
            null);

    try{
        if (c.moveToFirst()){
            return c.getString(0);  
        }
        return null;
    }finally{
        c.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: a contact may in many group, why don't you use loop for this case?

Comment: @vuhung3990 Sure you can do that, this is just the general idea.