# How to get group id by title?

Tags: java, android, contacts

I'd like to add a contact member to a group:

```
values.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID, groupId);
```

Currently I only have [TITLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.GroupsColumns.html#TITLE) of this group, how do I get `groupId` by this TITLE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to access `groupId` by `group name` you can call `getContentResolver().query( ... )` on content provider by passing `ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME` column name and it respectivelyvalue.

> Also you can look this seemed post [`Getting Contact GroupName and GroupId`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405985/how-can-i-get-a-groupid-groupname-of-a-contact-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is a full version of how to get the group id by its title. Basically it iterates all groups and compare titles to find its id.

```
private String getGroupId(String groupTitle) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI,new String[]{ContactsContract.Groups._ID,ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE}, null, null, null);     
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int len = cursor.getCount();

    String groupId = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Groups._ID));
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Groups.TITLE));

        if (title.equals(groupTitle)) {
            groupId = id;
            break;
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();

    return groupId;
}
```